# How to avoid almost duplicated uninformative type hints when function arguments should default to empty list/None

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Empty lists as default arguments is a gotcha in python, and adding type hints to the usual pattern of `=None` as default value make them quite messy.

Is there any way to avoid giving the type hint twice (or even once?) in this example code:

```py
class Telly:
    def __init__(penguin: Optional[list[str]] = None):  # <-- This type is ugly and adds negative value
        self.penguin: list[str] = penguin or []         # <-- Could this type be inferred?
```

(Example reworked from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

1. Is there anyway to avoid the `Optional` part of the argument type hint?
2. Can either of the type hints be inferred from the other?

For example if there was some special kind of default argument that would produce a new emptylist every time, or at least hide the ugliness of the type hinting, for example

```py
class Telly:
    def __init__(penguin=EmptyList[str]): 
        self.penguin = penguin or []
```

Would something like that be possible?

Comment: Isn't the right type _already_ inferred from `penguin or []`? See https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=bc1344edf5b0515cf0a44dd39c4e6457 - if MyPy couldn't work out that would always be a list, it wouldn't let you assign it with the explicit attribute type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes you are right, mypy does infer the type of the property from `penguin or []`. You can post this as an answer.

Comment: Not my DV but I would suggest simply avoiding type hints in general. "This type is ugly and adds negative value" sums up my feelings about the feature pretty well :)

Comment: @l4mpi yes, but sometimes type hints add a lot of value without being messy/verbose, (arguably this might be when the python code base is too big) and they make LSP `go_to_definition` work much more accurate/useful. Also, I'm not the only one writing the code I work with, so ways or conventions to curb bad type hints are nice to have.

Comment: Yes, something like that would be possible: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=4e72ccd8b775eac0ca4b17ab74e05f68 You can just _try_ these things.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wow, sorry for asking a question

Comment: Would stack overflow become better if I deleted this question?

Comment: You may be interested in https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-implicit-optional if `Optional` triggers you so much.

Comment: @STerliakov thanks, good input. I do think it's annoying, since it's necessary because of the python gotcha with default arguments that are modifiable. It's unfortunate. I dont't think I  will use the `--implicit-optional` flag because it makes the typing less standardized.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a type that hides the optional, for example:

```
from typing import Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
EmptyList = Optional[list[T]]


class Telly:

    def __init__(self, penguin: EmptyList[str] = None):
        self.penguin = penguin or []

    def whats_on(self) -> list[str]:
        self.penguin.append("property of the zoo")
        return self.penguin
```